# shmat() - perror returns invalid argument

Tags: c, linux

I tried to attach a char vector to a shared memory: *shmget()* is ok but *shmat()* returns an error.
This is my code:

```
...
...

#define TXTSZ 512

---main---
char *address;
int shm_id;
...
if(shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, TXTSZ*sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT | 0666) == -1){
    perror("Error shmget");
}
...
if((address = (char *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0)) == (char *) -1){
    perror("Error shmat");
}

...
...
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic mistake (usually made with `open()`). You're setting `shm_id` to the result of the comparison, not the ID returned by `shmget`.

You need parentheses around the assignment.

```
if((shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, TXTSZ*sizeof(char), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1){
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was going crazy!